# Fedora 17 yum update: could not finish packages updating

Tags: fedora, yum

After processing dependencies "yum update" produce errors:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: perl-CPAN-1.9600.01-215.fc17.noarch (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.14.2-215.fc17
           Installed: 4:perl-5.14.3-202.fc16.i686 (@updates/16)
               perl = 4:5.14.3-202.fc16
           Available: 4:perl-5.14.2-211.fc17.i686 (fedora)
               perl = 4:5.14.2-211.fc17
           Available: 4:perl-5.14.2-215.fc17.i686 (updates)
               perl = 4:5.14.2-215.fc17
Error: Package: 1:perl-IPC-Cmd-0.70-215.fc17.noarch (updates)
           Requires: perl = 4:5.14.2-215.fc17
           Installed: 4:perl-5.14.3-202.fc16.i686 (@updates/16)
               perl = 4:5.14.3-202.fc16
           Available: 4:perl-5.14.2-211.fc17.i686 (fedora)
               perl = 4:5.14.2-211.fc17
           Available: 4:perl-5.14.2-215.fc17.i686 (updates)
               perl = 4:5.14.2-215.fc17
```

There are plenty errors of that type mostly concerning perl.
But required version of perl is installed:

```
yum install perl-5.14.2-215.fc17.i686
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, presto, refresh-packagekit
Package matching 4:perl-5.14.2-215.fc17.i686 already installed. Checking for update.
Nothing to do
```

Skip broken option does not help.

It seems that upgrading from version 16 to 17 is stuck at the middle of process

Comment: This is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions). You might want to ask about this on [Unix.SE](http://unix.stackexchange.com) or [Super User](http://superuser.com) (but search for it there first!).

Comment: Thanks. I'll do it next time

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem after the upgrade from Fedora 16 to Fedora 17 (this upgrade sucks). It seems the perl-5.14.2-XXX.fc17 package does not show up in the repo update list because the version already installes (perl-5.14.3.fc16) is 'newer'. 
Here is what I've just done to solve the problem.

1. check which version you have already installed on you system:

   - perl-5.14.3.fc16
2. download the rpms for the newer version. In my case (you may need other libraries):

   - perl-5.14.2-211.fc17.x86_64.rpm
   - perl-libs-5.14.2-211.fc17.x86_64.rpm
   - perl-Carp-1.20-211.fc17.noarch.rpm
   - perl-Digest-MD5-2.51-211.fc17.x86_64.rpm
   - perl-Digest-1.17-2.fc17.noarch.rpm
   - perl-macros-5.14.2-211.fc17.x86_64.rpm
3. update allowing older packages (superuser):

   *# rpm -U --oldpackage perl-*.rpm*
4. Go back to yum update to finish updating missing libraries and packages.

If you still have some libraries dependence issues that doesn't allow you to to this you may have to remove thos libraries before, but normally it show go smoothly.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it by removing problem packages and installing them again after update finished.